# Is there an onto homomorphism between $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2019}?$

Tags: group-theory

Consider  the group  $\mathbb{Z} /2019\mathbb{Z}$  with addition  modulo  $2019$. which  of the following  groups  admit(s)  an homomorphism onto $\mathbb{Z} / 2019\mathbb{Z}$

$1. \mathbb{Z} /26247 \mathbb{Z}$  with  respect  to addition  modulo  $26247$

$2.$ $\mathbb{Q}$  with respect  to usual addition.

$3.$ $A=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \text{there exist}  \ n  \in \mathbb{Z} \  \text{such that} \  z^n=1\}$ with respect  to usual multiplication of  complex numbers.

$4.$$B=\{ z \in \mathbb{C}  : |z|=1\}$  with respect  to usual  multiplication  of  complex number

**My attempt** :

option $1$ is true take $f: \mathbb{Z}_{26247}\to \mathbb{Z}_{2019}$ defined by $f(x)=x$ is  an onto homomorphism

option $2$ is false since $\mathbb{Q}$  is not cyclic but $\mathbb{Z}_{2019}$ is cyclic

> Onto group homomorphism  map  a  cyclic to  cyclic

option $4$ is false .Take  $z=e^{2\pi i 2019 x}$.Then

$f(e^{2\pi i 2019 x})=2019 f(z)=0$

Therefore $f: B \to \mathbb{Z}_{2019}$ is not an onto homomorphism

Regarding option $3$, I am confused. What is the  way to check option $3$?

**My question** :Is there an onto   homomorphism between $A$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{2019}?$

Comment: Your argument for option $2$ is not correct. You have interchanged $A$ and $C_{2019}$. You cannot apply "Onto group homomorphism map a cyclic $A$ to cyclic $B$", because $A$ is not cyclic.

Comment: @durianice $A$ is not cyclic because $A=\cup_{n \in \Bbb N} \{z \in \Bbb C: z^n=1\}$

Comment: Your argument for option $1$ is not correct because the range of your proposed homomorphism is not limited to $\Bbb Z_{2019}$.  Notice that the same argument would work to "prove" the (false) claim that there is an onto homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_4$ to $\Bbb Z_3$.  If your argument would prove a false claim, you know there has to be something wrong with the argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you some hints here.

As in the comments, your argument for option 2 is incorrect.
The image of a homomorphism from a cyclic group is always a cyclic group.
This does not mean that a non-cyclic group must map to a non-cyclic group.
In fact, for any direct product $G\times H$, the projection $G\times H\to G$ is an onto homomorphism.
From this, we see that the non-cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ can map to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

For option 2, I suggest you look into some necessary conditions for a homomorphism to have an image of a cyclic group.
For example, suppose $f:G\to H$ is a such a map and let $f(a)$ be a generator of $H$.
Then $a$ itself must generate a subgroup $K$ of $G$ which is isomorphic to $H$.
If $G$ does not contain such subgroup, then we are done.
This should be enough for you case.

For option 3, as you pointed out in the comments,
the group $A$ in question is in fact a union of the groups of $n$th roots of unity.
Recall that the multiplicative group of $n$th roots of unity is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.
Compare this group $A$ to the example $G\times H\to G$ above.